# Automatically resize rofi menu height

Tags: scripting, rofi

I want `rofi` to automatically resize menu's height to the number of available options. There is an option `-lines` but with it I could only pass constant number. So for each call I'm forced to execute command twice - to calculate number of lines and to display menu:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
lines=$(my_command | wc -l)
my_command | rofi -dmenu -lines "$lines"
```

Is it possible to tell `rofi` to shrink its menu to the number of available options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `-no-fixed-num-lines` with `-lines <as-many-as-would-fit-on-your-screen>` as a maximum number of lines for `rofi` to adapt the size to the number of items to select from:

```
my_command | rofi -location 2 -lines 45 -yoffset 30 -dmenu -no-fixed-num-lines
```

Or you could save the output of your command in a temp file:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
function {
  rofi -dmenu -lines $(( $(wc -l < $1) )) -input $1
} =(my_command)
```

Here using `zsh`'s `=(...)` form of command substitution passed to an anonymous function.